# How to accessing properties of object Struct type, and then use it separately? (Swift)

Tags: arrays, struct, swift3

I need to assign a property of an object of type Struct. 
Here my Struct:

```
public struct Destinos: Data {
public var idDestino : Int?
public var desDestino : String? }
```

I have a 2 class when accessing he property like this:

```
class Api {
var listado = [Destinos]()

func GetDestinos(){
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 1, desDestino: "Asunción"))
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 2, desDestino: "Miami"))
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 3, desDestino: "Atenas"))
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 4, desDestino: "Londres"))
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 5, desDestino: "Madrid"))
}
}

class DestinoPresenter {

var ListaDeDestinos = [String]()
fileprivate var DestinoLista: Api!

func searchDestinos(_ substring: String) {

    DestinoLista = Api()
    DestinoLista.GetDestinos()

    //string member variable of each listados object
    for object in DestinoLista.listado {
        if  (object.desDestino?.lowercased().contains(substring.lowercased()))! {
            ListaDeDestinos.append(object.desDestino!)                
        }   
    }
    mview.mostarResultados(ArrayResultados: DestinoLista.listado) 
}
}
```

Method of another class:

```
func mostarResultados( ArrayResultados: [Destinos]) {
    autoCompleteDestino = ArrayResultados
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now for the method `mostarResultado` is where I just need to print `desDestino` property... I try different ways without success until now... help me please.

Comment: any help? please! i don´t find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
func mostarResultados( ArrayResultados: [Destinos]) {
        autoCompleteDestino = ArrayResultados
        for item in autoCompleteDestino{

         print(item.desDestino)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: yeah... but this is not solution in my case.  thanks any way... i will try in different way.

Comment: Kindly must share your solution, may be there is something to learn for me.